# Sewer smell in basement bathroom ONLY when central a/c is on

Tags: plumbing, hvac, ducts

whenever I turned on AC , I smell like sewer in Basement bathroom only. the rest of the basement and the house is all good. this happens only in Summer when AC is on- i checked the drain on Sink,Shower and no smell there.
no smell in Winter when Heat is on. Appreciate any suggestions and recommendations.

Thanks
Zaheer

Comment: Do you have any sinks or drains that you rarely use?  Maybe they have a "trap" that has run empty of water.  Put a pint of water down the drain should restore the trap.  Where does the condensate from the A/C condenser go?

Comment: Are you sure it's a sewer smell? If it's more musty, it could be dirty AC coils in the furnace. Several questions discuss this, try searching DIY.se for "smell when AC is running"

Comment: All sinks and drains are in use in basement. 
it does smell like sewer. i have a HVAC guy coming in on Thursday to tune up my AC. i will have him check the coils too in  furnace . they do plumbing as well.
thanks for your prompt responses.

Comment: @Triplefault wow, how do you clean the ACA coils, I must do that

Comment: Your main sewer pipe goes out from basement. It is about 4 inches thick. It should have a Y split with one end having a screw on cap. Check it for leaks,

Comment: @Ruskes I've never had it done myself, but I've read DIY.se questions with the method discussed.

Comment: here is the link to some more info i was looking into
https://www.doityourself.com/forum/air-conditioning-cooling-systems/452930-septic-smell-when-central-ac-running.html

Comment: i would check the vents. they might be almost clogged with birds nest, leaves, spiderwebs, etc. When it's almost-clogged, a small air pressure drop (like from the AC pushing basement air to the rest of the house) can pull in vent gases because there's not a strong enough updraft in the pipe.

Comment: @Ruskes I think you mean 4" in diameter.

Comment: @JACK my foult, yes 4 inch diameter

Comment: Unfortunately the smell is spreading slightly into other areas of home. i have scheduled a HVAC service on Thursday. will keep you posted .
thanks a lot !!

Comment: I had HVAC guy came in and checked AC and did his yearly maintenance- No fault there
Yesterday i had Plumbing team came in and they inspected the pipes and no leaks there as well. Smell continues to come thru.